# What is the best way to charge

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm currently using Late 2008 MacBook (Aluminum). My battery cycle is currently 111 and has went for replacement of battery 6 months ago + warrenty is ending soon. Hence I want to let the battery last as long as possible.

The common question are whether to charge my MacBook when using. But can I charge it for few more hours after it is fully charged? And also charge whenever I found a power source? So that the battery cycle will not increase tremulously.

What are the proper steps to charge MacBook batteries for long lasting life?

Comment: Please see this post Kim: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge

Comment: My general rule of thumb is to run the device (whatever it is) to flat at least once a month, and charge it to full at least once a month.  Other than that, don't bother charging until it's below 20%, and don't stop charging until over 80%, but no need to go to 100 every time.  Basically whilever it's between 20% and 80%, just use it.  I try not to drip charge it, 5% here and there where possible, once it's gone on charge I try to keep it there until it's at least 80%.Once I start using battery I try to keep using on battery until it's below 20%.Too many other variables to provide as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The battery cycle is exactly what it says, a cycle. This means that it will count charge and discharge cycles as a whole.

An couple of apple genius guys I talk to recommend at least 2 charge cycles per month, and trying not to leave it plugged in at all times will keep it relatively healthy.

You don't need to completely drain a battery before you charge it either, but the more complete the cycles are, the better accuracy will be on the battery meter.

It's a hotly debated subject, but apple do have information on their website.

http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html