# Are my battery cycle counts increasing when MBP is on and plugged in?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charge

I often leave my Macbook Pro (13" - Late 2011) plugged in while working on it with the charge at 100%. [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge) suggests that when the battery is at 100% and the laptop is plugged in, the battery stops charging altogether.

Let's say I use my computer in this configuration for 10 hours at a time. **Would this "cycle" of use actually contribute to my battery cycle count?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your battery is at 100% and your MacBook is plugged in then the battery isn't charging or discharging, so it isn't using a charging cycle.