# Can pmset's ChargeInhibit be used to prevent battery charging?

Tags: macos, battery, charging

I've been using my MacBook with AC power a lot lately and I thought that if I could use `pmset` to run on AC power whenever available and keep my battery at roughly 50% that would extend the life of my battery and AC adapter. I know that it's advisable to [regularly drain and recharge](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge) the battery.

I'm running OS X 10.10, Yosemite, on a mid-2012 Macbook Pro. I read that in Mac OS X 10.6 `pmset` could be used to prevent the battery from charging.

Is there any way to do this other than putting a piece of tape on the charger?

Comment: @GrahanMiln In my question I specifically asked if there were solutions _OTHER_ than putting tape on the charger, which is the top solution in the post this question is marked a duplicate of. Also, this question is linked to other posts where answers mention the SMC stopping charging when 100% is reached. However, I want to achieve a state of maintaining 50% battery while running on AC power.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question. I do appreciate the top voted answer is not what you are hoping for. There are currently four other answers. Between all five they represent the best solutions provided by the community.