# Does charging my early 2015 MacBook Pro all the time damage the battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, damage

I am using my early 2015 MacBook Pro as a desktop by connecting it to an external display, thus, it needs to be plugged in to a charger all the time.

Does charging my early 2015 MacBook Pro all the time damage the battery?
Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Have a look at: [Maximizing Battery Life and Lifespan](http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)

Comment: So, is there a way to connect to external display without the MPB charging?

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro with Retina Display, in Clamshell Mode and a Thunderbolt Display.  With the Thunderbolt Display connected and I remove power from the MBP, even though the Thunderbolt Display's power cord is plugged in, the screen goes black. So in this scenario with a Thunderbolt Display I can say no, power to the MBP is required to use the Thunderbolt Display. However when the MBP is opened normally, not in clamshell mode, and the Thunderbolt Display connected both screens remain usable when power is removed from just the MBP.

Comment: That's said, I cannot comment on other types of displays connected to a MBP, however I'd image the results would be the same under similar conditions.

Comment: Have a look at [this question and its answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12271/162909) for a little more information on leaving batteries plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends not leaving it plugged in all the time. This can damage the battery over time, as lithium-ion batteries need to be frequently discharged.

If you are going to use an external monitor, why not buy a desktop computer? MacBooks are made to be portable and have their batteries used.

Comment: You asked, "_If you are going to use an external monitor, why not buy a desktop computer?_", well the practical reason is being able to use the laptop as a desktop computer having a larger screen, wireless keyboard and mouse for more comfort and higher productivity while having the portability as/when needed and only having to own and maintain a single computer.  I use my MBP, in clamshell mode in a BookArc, most of the time connected to a Thunderbolt display however I do use it as just the laptop it is, when out and about and do drain the battery periodically.

Comment: Even if I had to replace the battery, it has been more convenient and much less expensive then having to have an iMac and MacBook Pro too.

Comment: Please provide a source for this Apple recommendation

Answer (score -1):

No, not at all. I leave my MacBook Pro connected to the charger for days on end sometimes and the battery still works fine. Once the battery gets to 100%, if it is still connected to the charger the MacBook stops charging the battery automatically and allows the battery to go down to 97%, then allows the battery to charge back to 100%, and repeats that cycle until you disconnect the MacBook from the charger. If you've ever charged your MacBook overnight only to find it at 98% or 99%, this is why.

Answer (score -4):

Keeping your Mac plugged in 24/7 is dangerous and will shorten the life of your battery exponentially. From imploding to starting a fire, you should only plug it in when needed. A while back I lost everything when I left my Mac (which was bought recently) plugged in for the week I went to Italy. The battery imploded and I was unable to retrieve anything. For safety and security, do not keep your Mac charging all of the time.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is utterly wrong. A MacBook of any form has circuitry designed to divert charge away from the battery once it is full (effectively running off AC). Your battery likely...did what it did due to other circumstances (age, damage, shorts etc).