# How to enable an unsupported HP Thunderbolt dock on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, thunderbolt

I have an HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 dock, and it will only charge my Mac. Any monitor or other external device it won't recognize.

I found [an article by 9to5mac](https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/21/tb3-enabler-enable-unsupported-thunderbolt-3-devices-hack-macbook-pro/) but tried it without success on macOS Catalina. I also tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1354372/dell-dock-tb15-on-macbook-pro-thunderbolt-charges-but-does-not-work) solution without success as well.

Does anyone know of any resource how to let macOS use docks which it lists as unsupported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to enable an unsupported HP Thunderbolt dock on macOS Catalina

#### Your question answers itself - it's not supported.

There's a huge misconception regarding the compatibility of devices being connected to a host computer; it's not limited to Apple, this is applicable across the entire industry.

**Just because a device is *identified* by the operating system, doesn't mean it's going to *work with* said operating system**.

For whatever reason, Apple has decided that this particular dock is not compatible.  It's a pretty safe bet that Apple isn't trying to prevent HP from encroaching on Apple's lucrative Thunderbolt 3 Dock business as Apple doesn't have one.

#### It's all about the sub-components

Just because a device utilizes a particular technology (Thunderbolt, USB, PCIe, etc.) doesn't mean that it will be compatible with your operating system.  That dock is much more than a "USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 Dock."  There's a video chip, a USB controller, audio (in and out), and even a network chip.  To make all those components talk to the PCIe bus (part of Thunderbolt), you need a *bridge* (it's another chip).  Any or all of these could be incompatible.

Thunderbolt (USB, PCIe, etc.) is merely the medium that connects peripheral devices to the host; you can think of it as the "road."  While a large 18 wheeler (lorry for our UK friends) works on the road it doesn't mean you're able to park it outside your house.  In other words, it's not compatible.

#### Manufacturer Blocks

Manufacturers put in these "blocks" to prevent you from using something because it's not supported.  It could simply not work or it could crash or even damage your system.

Remember, there are multiple sub-components on that dock and Apple doesn't include drivers for every single device on the market.  They include only what's necessary for *their* hardware.  Bypassing the block doesn't magically make these components compatible with each other.  Using the road analogy from earlier, you could pave a bypass around the imposed roadblock but, in the end, you still can't park that truck in your driveway.

#### But, it Charges!

Yes.  This is expected behavior.  Charging is a function that happens *outside* the scope of the OS.  You can charge your Mac when turned off and even if the drive has been wiped.  Your Mac and the dock are both [USB-PD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304575/119271) (Power Delivery) compliant meaning they both use the industry standard method to deliver power for charging.  Since it's outside the OS, there's nothing to block nor is there the ability to.

[Is the Macbook 12 inch's USB-C charger interchangeable with other USB-C chargers or devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/275543/119271)

#### TL;DR

Bypassing the block isn't going to make it work.  There are sub-components to that dock like video, network, and audio that also must be compatible with macOS.  If it was blocked by Apple or HP, it was done so for a reason - most likely there is incompatible or conflicting hardware present

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I haven't been on StackExchange for a while and didn't get a notification until yesterday's last answer. But, I now understand it completely. Really thanks for taking the time to explain this to me. Means a lot to me!

Answer (score 3):

Super smug answer, I'll add some less smug information - I have both HP Elite and G2 120W TB3 docks which worked 90% perfectly in 10.15 (with the unsupported patch installed) - sound, USB3.0, thunderbolt passthrough/USB-C video, networking and charging. The only thing that didn't work was the Displayport based outputs (and VGA I assume but I never tested that). They're all based off pretty standard chipsets and don
t need any drivers is MacOS.
So yes everything you say is correct but if you jump across to Bootcamp it all works so its all in Apples court really.

The unfortunate current situation is that from what I can tell there is no patches available for Big Sur to enable Thunderbolt so on my Elite I only have USB-C pass through video (quite happily doing 4KP60) and charging.
Lets hope something comes out in the future as there are lots of the HP docks turning up on eBay that are exlease and never used.

Comment: thanks for that info @lotech. Appriciate it.

Comment: How did you actually succeed with the patch? (not that I could use due Big Sur, but out of curiosity)  
When I posted this question, I was busy for days and days in a row in the evening to try to get it to work, without any success.

Comment: @BSM the answers provided above are misleading. Actually HP Elite Thunderbolt 3 dock and I use it at the moment of writing with MacBook M1 MacOS Monterey 12.4. The only thing needed was to install DisplayLink drivers from official site and I got display @ DisplayPort working. USB ports are working out-of-box. Ethernet isn't. Take a note of different revisions of the same dock and it's firmware

Answer (score 1):

I could get 2 external screens (hp e273q) working with the macbook pro m3 pro (sonoma) and a hp thunderbolt G2 120W (with the mac's display, so 3 in total). No need for displaylink or 3rd party app, it's just a matter of where to plug the cables at the back.

At the back of the dock, you have (from left to right) one USB-C, two DP, and one thunderbolt. You have to plug one screen with a thunderbolt cable into the thunderbolt port and one into the DP. You can't use both DP at the same time because of how Mac handles MST (multi-stream transport).

All USB / USB-C ports work fine for me. You may need to turn the thunderbolt off and on when the laptop comes back from a lock or sleep state.