# MacBook Air battery discharges overnight (April 2018)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

My MacBook Air's battery sometimes discharges overnight. Not always, perhaps just 60% of the time. It is always on sleep (I just close the lid) and it is usually for 8-9 hours. I unplug it, close the lid and head to bed. In the morning, it is at either 87% (most times) or 98% (some times) or 100% (rarely). I could not discern any pattern.

Specifications:

- 2017 13" MacBook Air (Purchased early 2019)
- macOS Mojave 10.14

What I tried so far:

- [TCP Keep Alive Setting](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8368663)

The issue is that I don't really know how to debug this.

Comment: “Plug it out” = unplug it?

Comment: Edited. Didn't know 'plug it out' is not a universal English thing, sorry :D

Comment: No need to unplug it overnight. You can leave it connected without any damage to the battery. See this question & answer [here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12271/should-i-disconnect-my-macbook-pros-power-cord-when-the-battery-is-fully-charge).

Comment: I live in a hostel. I do not have the luxury to leave it charging in the common area.

Comment: Turning off wifi and bluetooth helps to some extent.