# Would it be safe to keep my iPad connected to a power source for hours?

Tags: ipad, battery, thunderbolt, charger, charge

I have my iPad connected to my Samsung Smart Monitor M7 through the Thunderbolt cable continuously for hours so my iPad is charged all the time from the power available from the  monitor.

Is it safe to for the iPad’s battery to leave it connected  for a long run?

Comment: Also see:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12271/119271  I flagged as a dupe because we get this question a lot across all platforms and the answer is basically the same:  yes, it’s safe and  you won’t damage your battery.  By design, it’s protected from over/under current conditions that would lead to damage.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

As said very correctly [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253169361#:%7E:text=battery%20powered%20device.-,Every%20Apple%20battery%20powered%20device%20stops%20charging%20once%20the%20battery,days%20if%20you%20wish%20to.),

> You can't overcharge any Apple devices as there are ovecharging protections in these devices.
> So, no worry.

It's been almost four years I've have been using an iPad (6th gen) and I am charging it each night over night (battery reaches 100% at 12 AM and continues to charge until 7 AM). My battery still takes about 12-13 hours to deplete completely.